# NSFontPanel changeFont not called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, target-action, nsfontpanel

I'm trying to use a font panel in my Cocoa app and I can't get the changeFont: method to be called.

I had it working properly in another app and I just copied and pasted the code over but for some odd reason the changeFont method isn't called now.
Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)onOpenFontPanelBtnClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString* theFontName = [defaults objectForKey:DefaultFontNamePrefKey];
    NSFont* theFont = [NSFont fontWithName:theFontName size:12.0f];

    NSFontManager* fontMgr = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
    [fontMgr setTarget:self];
    [fontMgr setAction:@selector(changeMyCustomFont:)];

    NSFontPanel* panel = [fontMgr fontPanel:YES];
    [panel setPanelFont:theFont isMultiple:NO];
    [panel orderFront:self];
    panel.enabled = YES;

    NSLog(@"Font manager target: %@ (class: %@), action: %@", fontMgr.target, [fontMgr.target className], NSStringFromSelector(fontMgr.action));
}

- (void) changeMyCustomFont:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"New font: %@", [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] selectedFont]);
}
```

This code is being called from a view controller inside a modal window (preference window) and the font panel opens just fine. However, I'm not getting any changes although I set the target and action manually.

Is this problem related to the responder chain?
How can I fix it? Do I need to manually add the view controller to the responder chain? How would I do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't done this in a while, but setting the target/action on the shared font manager means that there can only ever be one handler for the entire process.  That doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added that code while trying to fix the issue. Thus, it also doesn't work when this is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question to help others that stumble upon this in the feature.
As I assumed, this issue was related to the responder chain.

My hierarchy was as follows: NSWindow (managed by NSWindowController) -> contentView -> childview (managed by NSViewController)

I found out that the responder chain ended in the window controller.
Thus, the font panel wasn't able to send the changeFont: message to the view controller where I implemented it.

By adding this line of code in the window controller I could fix the issue:

```
self.nextResponder = self.theViewCtrl;
```

What I still don't understand though is why it doesn't work when I manually configure target/action.
Anyways, it works for me now.

Comment: I have the same problem and would like to try your solution. But it's not clear to me what self is. Also, what if I have neither a window nor a view controller involved?